# How to extract .xab file?

Tags: file, extract

Tried by using fileviewpro but it is asking for paid services and also tried by changing file extension .xab to .exe, .txt, .doc, etc but it also not working it shows file in some other formats like binary or 0's and 1's.

After extracting file shows in this format:

> 0001 0000 5374 616e 6461 7264 204a 6574 2044 4200 0100 0000 b56e 0362 6009 c255 e9a9 6772 403f 009c 7e9f 90ff 859a 31c5 79ba ed30 bcdf cc9d 63d9 e4c3 9f46 fb8a bc4e f758 8537 3ae7 e4fa a6fd 1ae6 2215 bb60 6537 0b36 86d1 b0b1 1057 7643 bd0c c233 5cc2 165b fd16 1d2a 19d7 7c99 081f 98fd 1f82 6da2 435e 8466 5f95 f8d0 8924 8567 c61f 2744 d2ee cf65 edff 07c7 46a1 7816 0ced e92d 62d4 5406 0000 342e 3000

How can I extract the file?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Standard Jet 4.0 file header.  You have a lot of chance opening this file in Microsoft Access.